# Angular12/rxjs: updating observable data in template and showing changes in template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular12

So I have a livesearch going, fetching data based on the user input.

Example:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private httpHandler: HttpHandlerService) { }

      defaultSearchParams: SearchParams = { search: 'bla' }
      searchParams = new BehaviorSubject<SearchParams>(this.defaultSearchParams);
      myData$?: Observable<PageObjects<MyDataObject>>;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myData$ = this.searchParams.pipe(
          debounceTime(300),
          switchMap((searchParams: SearchParams) => this.fetchMyData(searchParams)),
        );
      }
    
      fetchMyData(searchParams: SearchParams): Observable<MyDataObject> {
        return this.httpHandler.getMyData(searchParams);
      }
}
```

My template showing the data:

```html
  <div *ngIf="(myData$ | async) as resultset$">
      <div *ngIf="resultset$.elements && resultset$.elements.length">
          <div *ngFor="let dataObject of resultset$.elements">
                ID: {{dataObject.id}}, name {{dataObject.name}}, status {{dataObject.status}}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Alright so here comes the challenge:
In my template, I want to be able to change data (i.e. new Name, new Status).

How can I reflect this changed data in the template when working with an observable object like me?

Sample of the desired result:

```html
  <div *ngIf="(myData$ | async) as resultset$">
      <div *ngIf="resultset$.elements && resultset$.elements.length">
          <div *ngFor="let dataObject of resultset$.elements">
                ID: {{dataObject.id}}, name {{dataObject.name}}, status {{dataObject.status}}
                <button (click)="changeStatus(dataObject)" type="button">Change status</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

```js
    changeStatus(MyDataObject dataObject) {
         this.httpHandler.changeStatusOfObject(dataObject, 'newStatus')
                .subscribe(newDataObject => //WHERE should I put the newDataObject to, to show the new value in the template???);
    }
```

Comment: What is `myData$.elements`?

Comment: elements is the object array holding the actual set of dataObjects

Comment: But `myData$` is observable, and you can't access the `elements` directly here. You should use `resultset$.elements` instead.

Comment: ahh gotcha sorry I messed up the variable names, will fix that in a second

Comment: Best practise would be to fetch again from your server. Because front end can't possibly know if back end really did what it was supposed to do. And with that it is  all simple then

Comment: As the backend returns the new value directly from the database after the change was made, we can safely use that data in the frontend as a valid reflection of the server data. Fetching all data again on every change made is something I would like to avoid

Comment: In that case, you cold store fetch results in outer state, like BehaviourSubject. And whenever server returns the change, you mutate what BehaviourSubject has and `next` the result to it. And `myData$` would be the Observable of that BehaviourSubject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you could use a `BehaviorSubject` to stream the data and also perform adjustments to it when you need to update a single item (without requesting the data from the backend). I would do it something like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private httpHandler: HttpHandlerService) { }

      defaultSearchParams: SearchParams = { search: 'bla' }
      searchParams = new BehaviorSubject<SearchParams>(this.defaultSearchParams);
      myData$ = new BehaviorSubject<PageObjects<MyDataObject> | null>(null);
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.searchParams.pipe(
          debounceTime(300),
          switchMap((searchParams: SearchParams) => this.fetchMyData(searchParams)),
        ).subscribe(pagedData => myData$.next(pagedData));
      }
    
      fetchMyData(searchParams: SearchParams): Observable<MyDataObject> {
        return this.httpHandler.getMyData(searchParams);
      }

      changeStatus(dataObject: MyDataObject) {
        this.httpHandler
          .changeStatusOfObject(dataObject, 'newStatus')
          .subscribe((newDataObject) => {
            // because now we have a behavior subject, we can get the last emitted value and use it to change just the updated object
            const pagedData = this.myData$.value;
            const elements = [...pagedData.elements];
            const updatedElementIndex = elements.findIndex(e => e.id === newDataObject.id);
            elements[updatedElementIndex] = newDataObject;
            this.myData$.next({
              ...pagedData,
              elements
            });
          });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `changeStatus` function to push the changes to the predefined `BehaviorSubject` `changes$`, which is combined with the searchParams observable to form `myData$` observable.

You can try the following:

```js
  changes$ = new BehaviorSubject<MyDataObject[]>([]);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myData$ = combineLatest([
      this.searchParams.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        switchMap((searchParams: SearchParams) =>
          this.fetchMyData(searchParams)
        )
      ),
      this.changes$,
    ]).pipe(
      map(([data, changes]) => {
        if (changes?.length && data?.elements) {
          changes.forEach((changedItem) => {
            const ndx = data.elements.findIndex(
              (item) => item.id === changedItem.id
            );
            if (ndx !== -1) data.elements[ndx] = changedItem;
          });
        }
        return data;
      })
    );
  }
  changeStatus(dataObject: MyDataObject) {
    this.httpHandler
      .changeStatusOfObject(dataObject, 'newStatus')
      // take one value from this observable and then complete it, to avoid memory leak
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((newDataObject) => {
        // push the newDataObject to the chagnes$ subject.
        this.changes$.next([newDataObject]);
      });
  }
```

Comment: That won't work unfortunately, changeStatusOfObject only returns the single object that was changed. Also it would break the livesearch;(

Comment: Ok, I got it. we should merge them together. I will update my answer now.

Comment: Could you check it now, please.